# static initialization in case of dependencies

Tags: c++, static

Is the following code safe (given no guarantees of static initialization order?).

In some library:

```
class A {
    A() : x_ = 0 {
    }

    int add() {
        return ++x_;
    }
};

namespace S {
    static A a_;
}

#define ADD(varname) \
    namespace S { \
        static int v_##varname = a_.add(); \
    }
```

Macro ADD will be used at multiple places. Is it guaranteed that a_ will be initialized before v_##varname for any ADD macro usage?

Comment: What do you mean safe -- does this even compile??

Answer (score 2):

There is a common trick for your case if you want to guarantee:

```
namespace S { 

A & getA() {
   static A a; 
   return a;
}

} // namespace S
```

And

```
static int v_name = getA().add();
```

Comment: Note that this can *Still* result in static destruction problems in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

In *the same translation unit/source file only*, any uses of `ADD` after the definition of `a_` will be executed after `a_` is constructed. In any other translation unit (library or application) all bets are off in terms of ordering of initialization.

You can use one of the static local methods if needed.

See the FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.15